# PHP timetable day issue

Tags: php

I've only included some of my timetable script (the part that deals with the days)

I noticed my timetable was working fine until the end of the month (everyday became a thursday) and so I went back into the script and I believe my timetable doesn't know when to detect if it is a new month so it continues to act like a counter 31, 32, 33 (day of month) which doesn't exist which is why it's giving me everyday as a thursday and saying the year was 1970.

The timetable shows 5 days from today - so it would show today and 4 others e.g. friday, saturday, sunday and monday.

**My code is as follows:**

```
       <?php
    }
    $timein = time();
    $d7 = date("H", $timein);
    $d6 = ($d7 +1) - 4;
    $d1 = date("d", $timein);

    $d2 = date("F", $timein);   
    $d3 = date("Y", $timein);
    $d4 = "$d2 $d3";
    $d5 = $d1 + 4;
    for( $i = $d1; $i <= $d5; $i++ ) {
    $day = strtotime( "{$i} {$d4}" );
    $day = date( "d/m/Y", $day );

    ?>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="20%" style="float: left;">
    <tr><td>
        <div class="square title" style="padding: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; width: 92%; text-align: center; bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #79CDCD;">

            <strong><?php echo $day; ?></strong>

        </div>
</td></tr>
</table>
<? } ?>
```

Is there a solution or an easier way to perhaps do this sort of script?

Thank you  for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

How about you just add 86400 seconds to `$timein` to increment your day?

Comment: You forgot about daylight savings time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems very hard to follow. That's usually not a good sign. I usually prefer a more object-oriented approach when dealing with dates:

```
$date = new DateTime();

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    ?>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="20%" style="float: left;">
    <tr><td>
        <div class="square title" style="padding: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; width: 92%; text-align: center; bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #79CDCD;">

            <strong><?php echo $date->format('d/m/Y'); ?></strong>

        </div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    <?php
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` to get the value for midnight today, and add `$i` days in your for loop

```
<?php

    for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
        $day = strtotime( "today + $i days" );
        $day = date( "d/m/Y", $day );

        ?>
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="20%" style="float: left;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="square title" style="padding: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; width: 92%; text-align: center; bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #79CDCD;">
                        <strong><?php echo $day; ?></strong>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As njk suggested you can also do it by adding multiples of 86400 seconds.

```
<?php

for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
    $day = time() + ($i * 86400);
    $day = date( "d/m/Y", $day );

    ?>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="20%" style="float: left;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="square title" style="padding: 3px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; width: 92%; text-align: center; bottom: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; cursor: pointer; background: #79CDCD;">
                    <strong><?php echo $day; ?></strong>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<? } ?>
```